Calculating marginal cost in a linear programming problem
I'm working with a simple linear programming problem that requires the calculation of a marginal price. The original formulation was very simple and I could easily calculate the marginal price(s) by re-running the LP with a change in the demand parameter. This process calculated the marginal price after the LP has solved.
However, the real-world problem has changed slightly and I now require the marginalPrice value to be available as a variable in the model. I am unsure how to formulate that problem and would appreciate suggestions. As you can probably tell, I'm not a mathematician.
Basic formulation
Every Monday, suppliers offer price and quantity pairs for supply of their product for the next seven days (T = [1...7]). We purchase quantities to minimise total cost while meeting some supply constraints. The formulation is quite simple:
$$ \min totalCost =\sum{P_{t} Q_{t,i} } $$
Subject to:
$$ Q_{t, i} <= qMax_{i} $$
$$ \sum{Q_{t,i}} = demand_{t} $$
There are a few additional shipping and blending constraints, but they are also quite simple. I've excluded them here for simplicity.
The price/quantity pairs look like this:



i
Company
Price
qMax




1
A
1
10


2
B
2
10


3
C
3
15


4
A
4
10


5
C
5
5



Marginal Price
Suppliers are paid a per-unit marginal price, and not their price/quantity offer price. For example, if D=40 then supplier A will be paid $4 x 10 (the marginal price), and not their offer price of $1 x 10.
Previously I would calculate the marginal price by re-running the LP with demand decreased by 1, so that the marginal price is calculated as the difference between the original total cost and the revised total cost.
New problem
A new policy was introduced that some suppliers must receive a certain minimum level of revenue. $$\sum{R_{i}} = \sum{(marginalPrice_{t} * Q_{i, t})} >= revenueTarget_{i} $$
How can I construct the model to define a variable marginalPrice[t]?
